# Silencing a Whatsapp group

Tags: settings, notifications, whatsapp-messenger

I would like to stop receiving new message notifications from a certain Whatsapp group. Is it possible?

**Clarifications:**

- I don't want to leave the group.
- I don't want to turn off all Whatsapp notifications. There are other groups from which I still want to get notifications.
- I don't want to just mute the notification sound. What I want is to get rid of the group's notifications entirely.

Comment: Sounds like something tasker might be able to do.

Answer (score 27):

Since WhatsApp version 2.11.399 and above for Android you can disable notifications when group is muted.

Follow this:

- Open your group which you wanna mute.
- Now go in 'Options' > 'Mute'.
- A dialog box will pop up and as of WhatsApp version 2.11.399 select the max period available to mute your group which is '**1 Year**'.
- **Untick** the 'Show Notifications' checkbox. Then click 'OK'.

You won't receive any notifications now from this group on your status bar.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: This is how it looks like]

Comment: Great, except it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Make sure you are on the correct version.

Comment: This does not work. I do have the option and I can uncheck the box, and maybe it disables the popup from the group but still shows notifications in the notification bar. Which is what I do not want.

Comment: This doesn't work. Whenever there's a new message, it is still the case that the group chat rises to the top, the green circle thing appears, and I can see the first few words of the latest message.

Answer (score 16):

The only thing you can do is to go into the Whatsapp group you want to mute. Then select `Menu` > `Mute` > `1 Year` and uncheck `Show notifications`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution which eliminates the notifications, not just their sound. Eliminating the notifications themselves is crucial for me.

Comment: @snakile I figured, but that won't be possible. It's possible to hide all the notifications of an app. But when you want to hide certain notifications of that app, that has to be an option in the app itself. And Whatsapp just doesn't have that...

Comment: Since WhatsApp version 2.11.238, its now possible to avoid notification for any respective group when it is muted. For more detail info please refer my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no solution where you disable notifications from one group and not the other.

However, if your question was "I want to get notifications only for individual messages and not group messages" (which was my situation that drove me to this page), here is an answer that may be helpful for other people browsing this page:

- Disable all WhatsApp notifications from Settings->Apps->WhatsApp.
- Open WhatsApp and enable *popup notifications* for message
  notifications (not group notifications).

Now, messages from individuals will appear as popup messages on your phone, so you sure won't miss them. Other than this, WhatsApp won't bug you for anything else, including notifications of group messages.

Answer (score 2):

**In iPhone**, you can solve the problem. Open group conversation. Click on group icon, then custom notification change for custom notification on. Change to sound silent and no vibration.

**In Android**, you can't solve the problem; only by turn off all notifications.

Answer (score 0):

In the Group Info page, go to "Custom Notification", then change it to disable sound, and disable Alert. 
maybe that will help?

Comment: I can't find any "Custom Notification" option in the Group Info page. Could you provide a screenshot please?

Comment: It's only available on iOS as of now.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you're asking about how to accomplish something with a specific piece of software that isn't a part of the native functions in that piece of software. It's like asking "how do I log into ICQ with Skype" -- well, it's not going to happen unless you can modify Skype to begin with. Unless Whatsapp is open source and you can hire a developer to write the function you need for you, or there is other software available for accessing the Whatsapp network where this functionality exists or can be added, you're not going to solve this no matter how high of a bounty you set on it.

The most pragmatic and realistic approach is to bug the Whatsapp developers about this until they add the function you want to the software (or stop forcing notifications).

Comment: You're right of course. I haven't expected that a huge bounty will magically solve my problem by adding a non-existing feature to whatsapp. What I'm hoping to get here is a workaround. I couldn't think of any but maybe someone else have. Even if a workaround doesn't exist, when this feature will be available on whatsapp, there's going to be an answer here which mentions it.